# Trying to fadeToggle() array of images in a single div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with an id - #hero. The content of the div will be images placed within an array which would need to be placed within the css for the id: #hero. I applied a fadeToggle effect and tried working the array of images to randomly fade in and out, with intervals.

I have been having issues trying to come up with a solution that works completely. For instance, this -

```
 $(function(){
           var transition_time = 5000;
           var waiting_time = 500;

           var pictures = ['0.jpg', '1.jpg', '2.jpg']; //array of images
           var n = pictures.length;
           var i;
           var res = '';
           var current = Math.floor(Math.random() * n);

           function f(){
               for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                   res += $('#hero').css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + pictures[current] + ')'}).fadeToggle(transition_time);
               }
           }
           setInterval(f, transition_time);
       })
   </script>
```

- simply fades in and out the first element within the array, and after count 3, it fades out leaving the div empty. It also does the fadeToggle without a graceful delay between each fading.

Please, how do i achieve the desired effect? I would really appreciate some feedback.

Comment: Can you post your markup as well, so we have a more complete picture of what you're trying to do? It seems like you want the images to fade in one by one after the interval passes? Can you more precisely explain the effect you're after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of issues with the way you have this function.

1. The random number is never being regenerated. (So if the page loads and the random number is 0, it will stay 0)
2. There is no need for the loop; essentially it is just rewriting the same code 3 times
3. The timed function will only fade the image in **every other run**. fadeToggle() will fade the #hero div in, next time it runs it will fade it out, then the next time it will fade it in.

Instead how about checking if the div is displayed. If not, change the image and display it. If it is, fade it out, change the image, then fade it in.

I used colors instead of images: https://jsfiddle.net/r8ntauk8/42/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var transition_time = 5000;
    var waiting_time = 500;

    var colors = ['#3f51b5','#009688','#ff5722']; //array of colors
    var n = colors.length;

    function f(){
        var current = Math.floor(Math.random() * n); 

        // If #hero is hidden (first time only) change the color, then fadeIn
        if($('#hero').css('display') == 'none') {
            $('#hero').css({
                'background-color': colors[current]
            }).fadeIn(waiting_time);
        }
        // if #hero is not hidden, fadeOut, change color, then fadeIn 
        else {
            $('#hero').fadeOut(waiting_time, function(){
                $('#hero').css({
                    'background-color': colors[current]
                }).fadeIn(waiting_time);
            });
        }
    }

    // run the function, then set the interval
    f();
    setInterval(f, transition_time);

});
```

Note: You may want to have a wrapper around the #hero div otherwise content underneath will shift up while the hero div is display none.

Comment: Thanks. It works. I messed up with the for loop as it only goes through the array length. I was thinking of a workaround this challenge, as images that were supposed to be looped was just the initial one. Thanks!